# Laravel IoC Container - Binding a singleton then returning it when you don't have the original params

Tags: laravel, singleton, ioc-container

We're trying to register a singleton e.g.

```php
$this->app->singleton('blah', function ($app, $options) {
    return $app->makeWith(Something::class, $options);
});
```

within the construct of `Something::class` we `logger('started')`

We then make the class via the container in a controller e.g.

```php
$something = app()->makeWith('blah', ['x' => 'y'])
```

We check the log, and you can see the `started`

Then elsewhere we try to pull it back out the container e.g.

```php
$instance = resolve('blah');
```

However the log shows another `started`

---

This would suggest that container is not returning the same instance as the construct is executed twice.

This is possibly because when we call `resolve` we're not passing in the same options that it was instantiated with.

If so, how can we get around this without setting a static variable somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you can create a singleton and use parameters at the same time. Here's the relevant code from `Container.php`:

```php
// If an instance of the type is currently being managed as a singleton we'll
// just return an existing instance instead of instantiating new instances
// so the developer can keep using the same objects instance every time.
    if (isset($this->instances[$abstract]) && ! $needsContextualBuild) {
        return $this->instances[$abstract];
    }
```

and then

```php
// If the requested type is registered as a singleton we'll want to cache off
// the instances in "memory" so we can return it later without creating an
// entirely new instance of an object on each subsequent request for it.
if ($this->isShared($abstract) && ! $needsContextualBuild) {
   $this->instances[$abstract] = $object;
}
```

Note that `$needsContextualBuild` is true if the instance is created using makeWith and parameters (in addition to when having a contextual binding).

If you want a parameterless `resolve` to always resolve the last resolved instance you can do something like:

```
//Bind or singleton doesn't matter now
$this->app->bind('blah', function ($app, $options) { 
    return $app->makeWith(Something::class, $options);
});
$this->app->afterResolving('blah', function ($resolvedObject) {
     $this->app->instance('blah', $resolvedObject);
});

$this->app->makeWith('blah', [ 'a' => 'b' ]); //New object 1
$this->app->make('blah'); //Reused object 1
$this->app->makeWith('blah', [ 'a' => 'b' ]); //New object 2
$this->app->make('blah'); //Reused object 2
```

Note that resolving the same alias with a different context will still resolve a new object and bind that object as the default instance of `'blah'`.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll see if I can swap it out to use your `afterResolving` technique and will report back once I'm on the project :) Thanks